# Concept of Time Division Multiplexing

Tags: multiplexing

I have been studying the concept of Time Division Multiplexing, but I have not been able to understand some stuffs, for instance, I have not been able to understand why the sampling rate for audio is `8Kbps` and then they say the frame length is `128ms`, I saw on another documents that the frame length would be `1/8000` which gives `128µs`, I am really getting confused, as a matter of fact I am confused, on another documents I was also asked to `Explain Time Division in terms of sources and their bit rates`. I would like some help on all these please, maybe a little explanation of the concept would be also good, so that I can view it from another persons point of view, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit wikepedia they've got a good document on this topic [Wiki Link](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing&ei=_xWPUsv4HqfE7AbUtYCwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEGgHn3k-Q4_5ozYh8hUgT5HJp3lQ&bvm=bv.56988011,d.ZGU)